# Best practice for using Source Link

Tags: .net, nuget, myget, sourcelink

I am trying to implement Source Link in a NuGet package. I have successfully implemented the instructions in the GitHub README (https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink), but am confused about which artifacts to upload to our NuGet package source (MyGet).

It seems that two artifacts are generated; a `.nupkg` and `.snupkg` file. MyGet returns a 409 response when I attempt to upload both to the same feed.

**So, what is the best practice for using Source Link? Is it to use a separate feed for the `.snupkg` files? Or, does MyGet just not support it yet?**

At the time of writing, I can't find an answer in the documentation or elsewhere.

I've currently switched to using the `.symbols.nupkg` format and am uploading that, which does work, but means that the symbol `.pdb` files are also bloating the package size.